# Acrobat JavaScript calculations with Radio Buttons & Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, pdf, conditional-statements, acrobat

I'm trying to write a Javascript calculation for an insurance sales form that I've designed. I'm very new to JS, and am having trouble getting the script to work. I would really appreciate if you could help point out what I'm missing! Thanks so much.

The script is meant to calculate an insurance premium based on two checkboxes (vars cb1 & cb2), a pair of radio buttons which indicate whether insured vehicles are for short or long haul trips (var haul), and the number of insured vehicles (vars trucks_num, cars_num, pvthire_num, buses_num, trailers_num).

At the end, I want the premium (var premium) to be displayed in the field "totalpremium".

I really appreciate your help!

Thank you :).

```
var cb1 = this.getField("cbexcellent");
var cb2 = this.getField("cbsatisfactory");

var haul = this.getField("haul");

var premium = this.getField("totalpremium");
var trucks_num = this.getField("over4.5t_num").value;
var cars_num = this.getField("cars_num").value;
var pvthire_num = this.getField("pvthire_num").value;
var buses_num = this.getField("buses_num").value;
var trailers_num = this.getField("trailers_num").value;

if((cb1 == "1") && (cb2 == "0") && (haul.valueAsString == "short")) {
var premium = (trucks_num.value * 150) + (cars_num.value * 100) + (pvthire_num.value * 250) + (buses_num.value * 150) + (trailers_num.value * 50);
}

if((cb1 == "0") && (cb2 == "1") && (haul.valueAsString == "short")) {
var premium = (trucks_num.value * 190) + (cars_num.value * 100) + (pvthire_num.value * 250) + (buses_num.value * 150) + (trailers_num.value * 50);
}

if((cb1 == "1") && (cb2 == "0") && (haul.valueAsString == "long")) {
var premium = (trucks_num.value * 190) + (cars_num.value * 100) + (pvthire_num.value * 250) + (buses_num.value * 150) + (trailers_num.value * 50);
}

if((cb1 == "0") && (cb2 = "1") && (haul.valueAsString == "long")) {
var premium = (trucks_num.value * 235) + (cars_num.value * 100) + (pvthire_num.value * 250) + (buses_num.value * 150) + (trailers_num.value * 50);
}

this.getField("totalpremium").value = premium.valueAsString
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is, exactly? Where is this going wrong? Are you getting any errors in your console? If you post your HTML markup, we can probably find an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the export values of your checkboxes match the values indicated as required in your if statements. By default these are set to Yes or No. If they don't match your script won't run right.